# php: how to add minutes to timestamp

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to easily add minutes to a timestamp in php.

I can do this easily in SQL such as `select now() + interval '60 minutes'` or using the `DATEADD` function, however I am not sure how to easily do this in PHP.

I have a date variable that I call as:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

And now I just need to add or subtract time from this.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time() + 3600);`

Comment: Take a look at the [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now +60 minutes'));
```

Which would give you the date 60 minutes in the future formatted the way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the timestamp is like this

$tmt += 2 * 60 * 1000; 
$date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $tmt);

Try this